# API Gateway Request Body Size limit exceeding after data transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint that is used for uploading files to the server. As part of the POST request, I create formData from UI and send it to my endpoint which invokes a lambda via the API gateway (APGW).

Recently I've come across a scenario where a user is trying to upload a zip file with a size < 5MB. The content of the zip file is a `.csv` file of size ~50MB. When this request goes to APGW, it tries to transform the POST request body. This I was able to see in the cloud watch logs of APGW. There I was able to see a "Method request body before transformation" section with the post data sent from UI, and then the next log is "Method request body after transformation", which again shows the same content as earlier in the before transformation log.

After this, the next log reads "Request body of size xxxxxxx bytes exceeds the maximum of 10485760 bytes" and the request errors out. I do understand that APGW has a limit of 10MB max payload allowed, but here as I said my file size is <5MB, so I'm assuming that APGW is trying to extract the zip file before sending the request to lambda, and there itself it's hitting the size limit and sending 413 entity too large error to UI.

Is this analogy correct or there is any other reason for this error? Can this request for body transformation be configured?[image: cloudwatch log]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: thanks, @ErmiyaEskandary for your suggestion. I added the image as additional info for anyone interested in taking a second look at the logs. Have explained everything in the post that is in the image and also ensured to remove anything sensitive from the image before uploading so I think it should be fine right?